# What can be said about $AA^+$ for symmetric real matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, duality-theorems, quadratic-programming, projection-matrices, pseudoinverse

Defining $A^+$ as the pseudoinverse of matrix $A$, what can be said about $AA^+$ if $A$ is a real matrix? What if $A$ is also symmetric?

The reason I am asking this is that I want to see why the following dual problem definition is true.$^\color{magenta}{\star}$

---

[image: screenshot]

---

<sub>$\color{magenta}{\star}$ Mahdi Jafari Siavoshani, [Duality in General Programs](https://dl.inl-lab.net/files/Courses/23-02-CO/Slides/Opt-12-Duality_GenCase.pdf), Convex Optimization, Sharif University of Technology, Spring 2023.</sub>

---

Related:

- [How to write the dual of quadratic program with positive semidefinite matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2362264)
- [Safe use of generalized inverses](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/184553)

Comment: What is the source of the screenshot?

Comment: Using the SVD, it's easy to show that $A A^+$ is a projection matrix

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo page 9 of https://dl.inl-lab.net/files/Courses/23-02-CO/Slides/Opt-12-Duality_GenCase.pdf

Comment: Again $A A^+$ is a projection matrix. Is that enough?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Not really. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/184553) answer provides the condition for using the pseudoinverse for solving the system of linear of equations, but its condition is different from the condition given in the slide.